# Unable to receive the entire data frame from Sqlite using R (dplyr)

Tags: database, r, sqlite

I am experimenting on manipulating data using R with remote on-disk data stored in Sqlite database. Here're my steps:

**Firstly**, I copied the `flights` data set to my empty test database:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
test_db <- src_sqlite("E:/Sqlite/test_db")
copy_to(test_db, flights, temporary = FALSE)
```

**Then**, I cleared R memory and attempted to extract the `flights` from test database:

```
library(dplyr)
test_db <- src_sqlite("E:/Sqlite/test_db")
flights <- tbl(test_db, "flights")
flights_df <- data.frame(select(flights, year, month, day, dep_time, tailnum))
```

Warnings poped up with

```
Only first 100,000 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.
```

Have no clue how to data frame the entire flights data which should include more than 300,000 rows.

Actually a **side question**:
Is that possible to do some advanced data manipulation (reshape, long data to wide data, wide to long) using R directly on the remote on-disk data in database instead of calling/data framing them in R which usually might cause memory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to bring the data back into an R data frame, you can use `dplyr::collect()`.

```
flights_df2 <- flights %>%
  select(year, month, day, dep_time, tailnum) %>%
  collect()
```

Comment: hrm... the code doesn't work at my end. Also is there any way I can massage the data on the server directly?

Comment: We need more details than "my code doesn't work". Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: Yes, you can modify data directly on data base. You might benefit from reading the [dplyr databases vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Another pretty useful doc I found is https://rpubs.com/justmarkham/dplyr-tutorial